# Aggregate Extension Method Not Supported (Linq to Sql)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I was trying to use Aggregate Method in linq to Sql but looks like it is not supported.

```
LibrarySystemDataContext ctx = new LibrarySystemDataContext();

var query = ctx.Books
  .Select(x => new
      {
        BookID = x.BookID,
          BookName = x.Title,
          Authors = x.AuthorBooks.Select(a => a.Author)
          .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, r) => sb.Append(r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName +"& "), sb => sb.ToString())
          });
```

to use Aggregate, i immediately converted books to IEnumerable as follows:

```
var query = ctx.Books.AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => new
      {
        BookID = x.BookID,
          BookName = x.Title,
          Authors = x.AuthorBooks.Select(a => a.Author)
          .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, r) => sb.Append(r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName +"& "), sb => sb.ToString())
          });
```

And, this is working. I want to know what will be the drawbacks or design flaws if i write queries like this.

Comment: which type is ctx.Books?

Comment: Depends on how big the DB is.

Comment: @BlackBear In database I have table called Book

Answer (score 1):

with `ctx.Books.AsEnumerable()` you will select the whole books table from database and start processing it in memory. This isn't good design. What you should do is, select the data you need and then process it locally.

for example

```
var temp = ctx.Books
  // probably some where clause
  .Select(x => new
      {
        BookID = x.BookID,
          BookName = x.Title,
          Authors = x.AuthorBooks.Select(a => a.Author)
          })
  .ToArray();

var books = temp.Select(x => new { 
    x.BookID, 
    x.BookName, 
    Authors = x.Authors.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, r) => sb.Append(r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName +"& "), sb => sb.ToString()) 
});
```

Comment: How is it better than the OP's solution? Basically you're just using ToArray instead of AsEnumerable, which causes all books to be loaded in memory at once...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque it isn't. until my comment '// probably some where clause' will be replaced with actual where