# Why Linq to Entities cannot convert this call to SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
var providerTypes = from provider_types in dbContext.vw_LookUpProviderType
                         select new vw_LookUpProviderType
                         {
                             ApplicationUser = provider_types.ApplicationUser,
                             ProviderTypeId = provider_types.ProviderTypeId,
                             Type = provider_types.Type
                         };


            var query =
                from providerCoi in dbContext.Provider_COI
                where providerCoi.COIProviderId == message.ProviderId
                join providerDetail in dbContext.ProviderDetail
                on providerCoi.ProviderId equals providerDetail.ProviderId
                into providerDetails
                from providerDetail in providerDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new Result
                {
                    PhysicianAdvisorId = providerCoi.ProviderId,
                    HasConflictOfInterest = providerCoi.COIFlag == true,
                    PhysicianAdvisorName = providerDetail.FirstName + " " + providerDetail.MiddleName + " " + providerDetail.LastName,
                    ProviderType = providerTypes
                        .Where(providerType => providerDetail.ProviderTypeIds.Contains(providerType.ProviderTypeId.ToString()))
                        .Select(providerType => providerType.Type)
                        .ToArray<string>()
                        .Aggregate((current, next) => current +", " + current)
                };
```

I have selected the providerTypes. There is table providerDetails, and  and there there is field providerTypeIds - this is can't be changed. For example `providerTypes: [1: 'Type 1', 2: 'Type 2', 3: 'Type 4']` and `providerTypeIds: '1,2,'`:

1. Select from providerTypes that types that can be found in providerIdsString
   `providerTypes.Where(providerType => providerDetail.ProviderTypeIds.Contains(providerType.ToString())) // => [1: 'Type 1', 2: 'Type 2']`
2. Than select on string representations: `.Select(providerType => providerType.Type) // => ['Type 1', 'Type 2']`
3. And finally transform all of them into string of types separated by comma:
   `.ToArray<string>()
                       .Aggregate((current, next) => current +", " + current) // => 'Type 1, Type 2`

And this is throws an exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Aggregate[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String],
>   System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String])'

Comment: You could make that a local collection first using AsEnumerable.

Comment: Enumerations are integers.  I often cast the enumeration to an (int).  You are converting to a string and then trying to enumerate a string which is characters.

Comment: @jdweng Firstly I have array of complex objects - `providerTypes`, than select from them some of them with `where`, then transform them to array of strings by `select`, and finally join array to string with `Aggregate`. `objects[].Where(f => condition).Select(f => f.field).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next)`

Comment: [`Aggregate` just isn't supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities#aggregate-methods).

Comment: @Rawling Thanks, you can post an answer if want, or I will do it myself later :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999319/aggregate-extension-method-not-supported-linq-to-sql

Comment: @Nikita I'll leave off adding an answer in case someone decides to come up with a workaround for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as was mentioned in comments, Aggregate function is not supported in Linq to Entities, see ref for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities#aggregate-methods

Unfortunetely simple toList, didn't help me, I don't know the certain reason, but maybe it because of use field for search - `providerTypes`, maybe toList on the `providerTypes` could help, but I've used another workaround - select physicianIds string, and then manualy transform it. See code below.

```
//select provider types lookup, from there can map id with it text meaning, f.e.[{providerTypeId: 1, type: 'Value 1' },{providerTypeId: 2, type: 'Value 2' }]
var providerTypes = exUrDataContext.vw_LookUpProviderType.ToList();

//select physicianCois with unmodified providerTypeIds(f.e '1,2,')
var physicianCois =
                await (from providerCoi in dbContext.Provider_COI
                       where providerCoi.COIProviderId == message.PhysicianId
                       join providerDetail in exUrDataContext.vw_ProviderDetail
                       on providerCoi.ProviderId equals providerDetail.ProviderId
                       into providerDetails
                       from providerDetail in providerDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new Result
                       {
                           PhysicianAdvisorId = providerCoi.ProviderId,
                           HasConflictOfInterest = providerCoi.COIFlag == true,
                           PhysicianAdvisorName = providerDetail.FirstName + " " + providerDetail.MiddleName + " " + providerDetail.LastName,
                           ProviderType = providerDetail.ProviderTypeIds
                       }).ToListAsync();

            //map string with ids to string from text values, f.e. '1,2' => 'Value 1, Value 2'
            foreach (var physicianCoi in physicianCois)
            {
                string physicianProviderNames = "";
                foreach (var providerKey in physicianCoi.ProviderType.Split(new char[] { ',' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    if (!physicianProviderNames.Equals(""))
                    {
                        physicianProviderNames += ", ";
                    }
                    physicianProviderNames += providerTypes.Where(providerType => providerType.ProviderTypeId == int.Parse(providerKey)).FirstOrDefault().Type;
                }
                physicianCoi.ProviderType = physicianProviderNames;
            }
```